# New tester added to active Closed Test in Play Console don't have access

Tags: android, google-play

We have a Closed Test on Play Console for our Android App with a Build that was successfully reviewed by Google. We were testing with a group of Testers added via Email-list "testgroup A".

Recently we've added an additional Email-list "testgroup B" with further testers to the Closed Test. All users recently added don't have access to the App. Even if I add those new users to "testgroup A" they don't have access. All emails are connected to an Google Account.

Does anyone know what the problem is?  How do I add new users to an active Closed Test in Play Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've turned on [managed publishing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en) and forgot to approve the changes on the page Publishing overview. After approving the additional Email-list "testgroup B" all users had access to the App.